# Product's Custom Attribute ISN'T updating on the ADMIN PAGE

Tags: magento2, product, admin, api

I'm beginner at Magento 2 and i'm trying to **update an attribute value from a specific product**.
The update works on the API, but seems to have not updated on the admin page. What could it be? Any help is useful.

Comment: look in log file for error

Comment: Actually there is no errors. To be honest, if use a Get request on the Postman, it shows the value updated, but on the Admin Page it don't update.

Comment: check in the database looking at product id.. maybe with api get the product you've just updated and see the details match the database.. and then do same process from backend